# Kibana search preference

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-7, kibana-7

My Elasticsearch cluster is split in fast and slow nodes. If I am manually querying by REST, I'll use the preference query parameter (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-search.html#search-preference) to specify that I'd like the search to occur on a fast node.

I can't do the same in Kibana so how can I setup such that Elasticsearch/Kibana will search on the fast nodes if they are available, falling back to the replicas on the slow nodes as required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way Kibana specifies the `preference` parameter by configuring this in Stack Management > Advanced Settings and then changing the following settings:

- courier:setRequestPreference = Custom (instead of SessionID)
- courier:customRequestPreference = _only_nodes:

Then it should work the way you expect.